# Get a property pointer when you have the name as a string

Tags: ios

I am trying to set a value from a property that I have the name of in a string but need its pointer. (I believe)

I have:

```
unsigned int propCount = 0;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &propCount);

for(int idx = 0; idx < propCount; idx++) {
    objc_property_t prop = *(properties + idx);
    NSString *key = @(property_getName(prop));
    NSString *key2 = @(property_getAttributes(prop));

    NSLog(@"%@::%@", key,key2);

    if ([key2 rangeOfString:@"UITextField"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"is a uitextfield");

        [self.form setValue:self.comments forKey:key];
    }
}
```

key = "comments"

Instead of using self.comments I want to use something like self.key but I know I cant do that. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is use **Key-Value Coding**. You can replace references to `self.comments` with `[self valueForKey:key]` were `key` is `@"comments"`. If you want to do a simple check to make sure they are pointing at the same memory address, use this:

```
NSLog(@"%p %p", [self valueForKey:key], self.comments);
```

Comment: I thought that this would work but I get `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Survey 0x816b110> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: the entity Survey is not key value coding-compliant for the key "comments".'`

Comment: Oh man I was pointing to the wrong class in coredata! thank you for pointing out key-vaule coding that was very helpful in figuring that out.